# aws data pipeline datetime variable

Tags: variables, datetime, amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I am using AWS Data Pipeline to save a text file to my S3 bucket from RDS. I would like the file name to to have the date and the hour in the file name like:

```
myfile-YYYYMMDD-HH.txt
myfile-20140813-12.txt
```

I have specified my S3DataNode *FilePath* as:

```
s3://mybucketname/out/myfile-#{format(myDateTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH')}.txt
```

When I try to save my pipeline I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve myDateTime for object:DataNodeId_xOQxz
```

According to the [AWS Data Pipeline documentation for date and time functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-pipeline-reference-functions-datetime.html) this is the proper syntax for using the *format* function.

When I save pipeline using a "hard-coded" the date and time I don't get this error and my file is in my S3 bucket and folder as expected.

My thinking is that I need to define "myDateTime" somewhere or use a NOW()

Can somebody tell me how to set "myDateTime" to the current time (e.g. NOW) or give a workaround so I can format the current time to be used in my *FilePath*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not aware of an exact equivalent of NOW() in Data Pipeline.  I tried using makeDate with no arguments (just for fun) to see if that worked.. it did not.

The closest are runtime variables scheduledStartTime, actualStartTime, reportProgressTime.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-s3datanode.html

The following for eg. should work.
s3://mybucketname/out/myfile-#{format(@scheduledStartTime,'YYYY-MM-dd-HH')}.txt

Comment: +1 Thank you. Yes, using **@scheduledStartTime** instead of "myDateTime" did the trick. I also just read that _a [user-defined field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-writing-pipeline-definition.html#dp-userdefined-fields) must have a name prefixed with the word "my" in all lower-case letters, followed by a capital letter or underscore character._  I also found other variables/[objects for the CopyActivity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-copyactivity.html)

Comment: and how to subtract a date here in this format because I am unable to do so

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is some more info on `Parameters`.

At the end of your Pipeline Json (click `List Pipelines`, select into one, click `Edit Pipeline`, then click `Export`), you need to add a `Parameters` and/or `Values` object.

I use a `myStartDate` for backfill processes which you can manipulate once it is passed in for ad hoc runs. You can give this a static default, but can't set it to a dynamic value so it is limited for regular schedule tasks. For realtime/scheduled dates, you need to use the `@scheduledStartTime`, etc, as suggested. Here is a sample of setting up some `Parameters` and or `Values`. Both show up in `Parameters` in the UI. These values can be used through out your pipeline activities (shell, hive, etc) with the `#{myVariableToUse}` notation.

```
"parameters": [
{
  "helpText": "Put help text here",
  "watermark": "This shows if no default or value set",
  "description": "Label/Desc",
  "id": "myVariableToUse",
  "type": "string"
}
]
```

And for Values:

```
"values": {
  "myS3OutLocation": "s3://some-bucket/path",
  "myThreshold": "30000",
}
```

You cannot add these directly in the UI (yet) but once they are there you can change and save the values.